# Use variable in offset and length in table expression component?

Tags: abap, internal-tables

I am trying to see if there is a way to do the following

```
IF line_exists( company_accounts2[ saknr+0(2) = wa_company_accounts-saknr+0(wa_account_levels-num_of_digits) ] ).

  ENDIF.
```

But the number 2 in **saknr+0(2)** with a parameter and specifically with the one that exists in the other side of equality (wa_account_levels-num_of_digits). Is there any way to do it with another way? Because if I replace the 2 with the wa_account_levels-num_of_digits I am getting the error "The length specification "WA_ACCOUNT_LEVELS-NUM_OF_DIGITS" is not numeric."
Thanks in advance

PS. What is not working and this is what I am asking below the above code is the following code:

```
IF line_exists( tab[ matnr+0(ls_mara-num_of_digits) = ls_mara-matnr+0(ls_mara-num_of_digits) ] ).
```

THIS CODE IS NOT WORKING.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem with [this test program](https://pastebin.com/dZyAf4FW). Perhaps `WA_ACCOUNT_LEVELS-NUM_OF_DIGITS` is *indeed* not numeric? What exactly is its type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the left side of the equality as a [text variable between parentheses, which contains the name of the variable and its offset](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenitab_components.htm):

```
  DATA(lv_text) = |saknr+({ wa_account_levels-num_of_digits })|.

  IF line_exists( company_accounts2[ (lv_text) = wa_company_accounts-saknr+0(wa_account_levels-num_of_digits) ] ).
    CONTINUE.
  ELSE.
    "make the APPEND
  ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 1):

It works perfectly, for what you wanna achieve your `wa_account_levels-num_of_digits` should have primitive type `i` (`INT1`, `INT2`, `INT4`, `INT8` in database).

Here is the working MARA sample

```
SELECT * UP TO 5 ROWS
FROM mara
INTO TABLE @DATA(tab).

READ TABLE tab INTO DATA(ls_mara) INDEX 1.

IF line_exists( tab[ matnr+0(2) = ls_mara-matnr+0(ls_mara-stfak) ] ).

ENDIF.
```

**UPDATE**: dynamic specification of the table components for read access [is not possible](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenitab_components.htm):

> If the data type of the components is character-like and flat, an offset/length +off(len) can be appended to the name of the component (as in substring access) to access subareas of the component. **Only directly specified numbers or constants can be specified for off and len**.

Comment: This code I know that working. But I want to parametrize the left side of the equality.